# Need regular expression for a string which accepts expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for a string which can be

```
abc -> valid
abc-${test_name/test.name}-123 -> valid
abc-${test.name-123 -> invalid`
```

I tried with these

```
^[a-z0-9-$^\{.*\}$._]+$

^\{.*\}$
```

and also

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*-\${[a-zA-Z0-9]*}-[0-9a-zA-Z]+$
```

but does not work as expected

Comment: You might need to escape the curly brace characters

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on your spec. What property are you trying to validate? Where are the strings (hint: put quotes around them)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but try this: `^[^-]+(\-\$\{[^}]+\})*(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: You may use: `^(?:\$\{[^}]+\}|[\w-])+$`

Comment: i think this is working ^[^-]+(\-\$\{[^}]+\})*(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$ , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/^[a-z]+(?:-\${[^{}]*}(?:-\d+)?)?$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bLXdyN/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]+` - one or more letters
- `(?:-\${[^{}]*}(?:-\d+)?)?` - an optional string of

  - `-\${[^{}]*}` - `${`, any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`
  - `(?:-\d+)?` - an optional string of `-` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

See JavaScript demo:

```js
const strings = ['abc', 'abc-${test_name/test.name}-123', 'abc-${test.name-123'];
const regex = /^[a-z]+(?:-\${[^{}]*}(?:-\d+)?)?$/i;
for (let s of strings) {
  console.log(s, '=>', regex.test(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Work for all your examples. Try:

```
/^[\w-.]+$|^[\w]+-?\$\{[\w\/.]+\}-?[\w]+$/
```